# Authenticate new user with passport.js only after email verify

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org) with [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) (mongoDB) (and [passport-local-mongoose](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose)) to create and authenticate user accounts in a node/express backend.

The strategy I'm currently using is:

- User completes a signup form, with a `username` input `type="email" name="username"` and a `password` input `name='password'` (among others)<sup>*</sup>
- User submits form.
- Add new user to a Profile schema `let newUser = new Profile({username: req.body.username, ...})`
- Generate a token using `crypto.randomBytes(...)`
- `Profile.register(newUser, password)` & `passport.authenticate` user and set token field generated from above set, along with an expiry date
- Send an email to new user, with a url containing their mongoose `_id` and their token (`/u/${id}/is-valid/${token}`).
- On visiting this url, `Profile.findOne({_id: req.params.id})` and check that the tokens match, and has not expired
- If not, send them to the login page.

Then problem with this approach, is that in calling `Profile.register` and `passport.authenticate` together, a pre authenticated account is created before the user has validated their email.

**How can I decouple these two methods so that I can authenticate users only after they've verified their email address?**

Here is how I call `Profile.register` and `passport.authenticate` (as part of an `async.waterfall([])`:

```
Profile.register(user, pw)
    .then(response => {
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(err) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            user.resetEmailToken = token;
            user.resetEmailExpires = Date.now() + 8.64e+7; // 1 day

            user.save(function(err) {
                callback(err, token, user);
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return callback(err);
    });
```

I would like to `Profile.register` as I do above, but only `passport.authenticate` once I've checked the tokens.

Here is how I check the tokens (on visiting link contained in email - `/u/${id}/is-valid/${token}`):

```
async verifyEmail(req, res, next){
    let user = await Profile.findOne({ '_id': req.params.id })

    if(!user) return res.redirect("back");

    if (user.resetEmailToken != req.params.token){
        req.flash("error", "Tokens don't match");
        return res.redirect("back");
    }

    if(user.resetEmailExpires < Date.now()){
        console.log("This date has expired", moment(user.resetEmailExpires).calendar());
        return res.redirect(`/signup?token-expired=${user.email}`);
    }

    user.isVerified = true;

    // Here is where I want to passport.authenticate() and redirect to their new profile

    user.save();

    return res.render('login', { user: user });
}
```

If this is not possible, what are other approaches I could take to achieve this? It must be a fairly common signup strategy.

* <sub>This is a bit of a hack as passport.js assumes registration with username & password (not email)</sub>

Comment: eliminate the use of a password and use jwt perhaps?

Comment: @iRohitBhatia sound like an option, but there must be a way to do this with passport js? I feel like I must be missing something

Comment: Passport is for session management and authentication, if you want to do it with passport then don't use passport during the initial signup phase, and use it only for login. Does that make sense?